# Why dimension units of radius is not $\rm m/rad$ or $\rm cm/rad$?

Tags: angular-momentum, dimensional-analysis, units, rotation, angular-velocity

Radius is not a just simple size or length between the two points. The radius shows the connection of linear and angular values. Something must indicate the information about a perpendicularity of the radius to the angular values. This something may be radian at dimension units of radius. So if$$\left[ r \right] = \frac{\text{m}}{\text{rad}}$$then for example
$$\left[ {\omega  = \frac{v}{r}} \right] = \frac{\text{m/s}}{\text{m/rad}} = \frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}} \ne \frac{1}{\text{s}} = \left[ f= \frac{v}{C} \right]$$
$$\left[ {\tau = F \cdot r} \right] = \frac{\text{N} \cdot {\text{m}}}{\text{rad}} = \frac{\text{J}}{\text{rad}} \ne \text{J} = \left[ W = \int {Fdx} \right]$$

The reference to a radian as a primary issue may be logically incorrect, because often dimension units of the radius is used in the proof of a radian dimensionless . As a result, the issue of dimension units of the radius becomes primary before a considering of a radian.

Why dimension units of a radius is not $\rm m/rad $ or $\rm cm/rad $? Where $\rm m $ or $\rm cm $ is from a ruler (or a line gauge or a scale) and $\rm /rad $ is from a goniometer (or a 90° protractor or something similar), which is necessary additionally to a ruler for the definition of a perpendicularity of the radius to the angular values.

Comment: Rad is not a unit, because it measures the ratio of two lengths, and hence unitless.

Comment: No. It is logical error: "proof through the same". The dimension unit of radius cannot be proved through dimension unit of andle, which proved through dimension units of radius.

Comment: Angles are dimensionless quantities. The units of $\omega$ is $s^{-1}$ and that of torque is $N m = J$

Comment: It is just a statement of generally accepted well known convention. It is not the answer to the question "Why dimension units of radius is not m/rad?".

Comment: You start with the assumption that the radius is defined as meters per radian, but then your algebra shows a contradiction, indicating your assumptions cannot be true. This rather looks like a proof that radius is not measured in meters per radian.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252288/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37881/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic This question is not about radian, but about the radius. And Nullius in Verba gave an accurate answer, which is absent from the specified link. The question about the dimension of the radius is primary in relation to the dimension of Radian. Since provenly through the dimension of the radius is often used in an explanation of Radian's dimensionality. That question is secondary and therefore there is no answer to the rear question here, but there is a lot of an excess. But here the important answer is given to this formulation. This question without editing is not a duplicate.

Comment: Nullius in Verba's answer seems to fit equally well at the duplicate thread.

Comment: Tip: To reopen this post (v3) and a second opinion from reviewers, consider to edit post stressing difference.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can make as many units as you'd like.  You can give Force and acceleration their own units, not derivable from base units, so that $F=ma$ has to be written as $F=Jma$, where $1 kgf = J*(1kgm)*(1 g)$, and the factor $J$ is needed with units $kgf/(kgm*g)$. Indeed, the American system does a version of this.  So you are not wrong in choosing your unit for radius, but it's wrong to say that other choices are incorrect.  Physical conventions are ultimately driven by what is most useful to solve real problems.

Comment: In theoretical physics, physical laws are often written with no units at all (e.g. Planck units).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something like what you are trying to do here if you consider "metres in the x direction" and "metres in the y direction" to be distinct units with vectorial properties.

If we write $\text{m}_x$ for "metres in the x direction", $\text{m}_y$ for "metres in the y direction", then

$$\left[ {\omega  = \frac{v}{r}} \right] = \frac{\text{m}_x/\text{s}}{\text{m}_y} =  \frac{\text{m}_x \text{m}_y^{-1}}{\text{s}}= \frac{\text{rad}_{xy}}{\text{s}} $$

Here $\text{rad}_{xy}$ means "radians measured in the $xy$ plane". It's a signed quantity, positive as you rotate (either clockwise or anticlockwise) from $x$ to $y$.

We can do this a little more formally if we consider spatial *units* to be standardised quantities that can have vector, [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector), etc. geometrical properties. They are not all scalars. When we talk about "length" now we are talking about the ratio of the vector between the two points being measured and a standardised *unit* vector pointing in the same direction. We can legitimately divide vectors pointing in the *same* direction by one another and get a scalar quantity, because a scalar times a vector gives another vector that is some multiple of it. But when we divide a vector by another vector pointing in a *different* direction, this is no longer true. Instead we get a *bivector* quantity that represents a plane area in the same way vectors represent linear lengths. Bivectors are the generators of rotations. And in the case of circular motion, comparing a velocity vector in the tangential direction to the radius in the radial direction gives us a bivector quantity with an orientation 'pointing' in the plane of rotation.

Then making the claim that the units of radius are $\text{m/rad}$ is actually just saying $\text{m}_x/\text{m}_x\text{m}_y^{-1}=\text{m}_y$, we are converting metres in the $x$ direction to metres in the $y$ direction. The magnitudes of the standard metre vectors in every direction are the same, so the radian unit has a scalar magnitude of $1$, but is not actually the scalar $1$, but instead a bivector quantity with an orientation in space.

Using oriented units usually just complicates things, and it is normal to use only the scalar magnitudes of units. But it can sometimes be useful or insightful. If you do dimensional analysis keeping length units in different directions separate, it can sometimes resolve ambiguities that the scalar version of dimensional analysis fails to distinguish.

[Geometric Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) is a system that is capable of doing this correctly, keeping everything straight, even when mixing directions that are not orthogonal to one another, although in practice practioners of Geometric Algebra usually do it the same way everybody else does.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer. Indeed, Not the attachment of the curvature to the radius or the radius to the curvature by dividing by radian must be indicated. But the perpendicularity of the radius to the angular values must be indicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by saying that the way "frequency vs angular frequency" and the unit "radian" is taught in high school/secondary school is really awful... they make it sound like they're going to use radians as a unit all over the place but then they forget it in a lot of equations, leaving students confused.

Can you measure it with a ruler? Yes. Then it has units of length. As people have said in comments, if you use a convention where $1\text{ rad}=1$, then the problem is solved altogether.

If you desperately want to use an inconvenient system where the "unit" radian is carried with you all over the place, then you can say "the radius is $r=1\text{ m}$, and the arc length of an arc with angle $\theta=\pi\text{ rad}$ is  $r\theta/\text{rad}$." If you even more desperately want to use a system where radius is measured in $\text{m}/\text{rad}$, that makes the arc length equation nicer ($r\theta$), but it makes other equations like the area of a slice of circle pretty ugly (normally $r^2\theta/2$ becomes $r^2\theta(\text{rad})/2$).

Both systems that explicitly use "rad" become really annoying when you think of simple harmonic motion. You'd have to say the angular frequency of a pendulum is $\omega=3\text{ rad}/s$. Then the angular position as a function of time is $\theta=\theta_{\text{max}}\cos(\omega t/\text{rad})$, assuming cosine has its usual mathematical definition and can be written as:
$$
\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+O(x^4)
$$
I personally use a system where $\text{rad}=1$, and $1\text{ whole cycle}=2\pi$. I then assert that, for example, $\hbar=h=1.054\times10^{-34}\text{ Js}=6.626\times10^{-34}\text{ Js}/\text{cycle}$ and $\omega=f$ (angular frequency and frequency are the same thing). I accept this isn't a commonly used system but I think it makes things a lot simpler. Suffice to say you can choose which system to use with regards to how you deal with angles and frequencies, but you shouldn't make an inconvenient choice that introduces a whole bunch of cumbersome notation.

Comment: No. I can not measure radius with a ruler! Only I can measure distance beetween two points with a ruler. But befor that I must to determine the points based on curvature. The radius contains more information than just simple the distance between two points. It also indicates the presence of curvature, which is associated with these points.

Yes. Some expressions will become more bulky. But will they not be more strict?

Comment: @Imyaf The radius of a circle is the distance between the center and any point on the outside. But if you want to use a system where the radius is that distance divided by 1 radian and 1 radian is not the same thing as 1, go for it. I think that system is pretty bad, but you do you. In academic writing you will need to use a more widely accepted system because nobody will know what you're talking about. In general I'd say your contention could apply to all quantities - they all have more meaning than the units alone would imply, and you can only use them in certain valid equations

Comment: But before that, the center must be found. But before that, the curvature must be measured to prove the presence of a circle. So the radius contains more information than a just simple distance between two points.

Comment: @Imyaf I'll say again: a similar contention could be applied to all measured quantities, and baking the meaning of a every quantity into its units seems really cumbersome to me. We all need to be aware that every quantity has more meaning than just the units that it has, and should only be used in equations that actually apply to that quantity. We don't need our units to extra enforce this