# How can Torque and Work have the same dimensions (both can be expressed in N.m because Joules = m.N = N.m) but they represent diffrent quantitie?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, torque, dimensional-analysis

So torque and work are both distance times force but how can they be so different conceptually? I understand the torque is an outer product and is a vector while work is a dot product and is a scalar but I still don't understand how can two things measured with basically the same units express different concepts and convey different information?

Comment: It just so happens that the multiplication of a force by a displacement in two different ways produces two useful quantities.

Comment: @Farcher Thank you for your response! I was wondering where is the information encoded tho? My intuition would have been in the units but this poses a problem for that.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Why is torque not measured in Joules?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37881/2451) and links therein.

Comment: Torque doesn't necessarily produce work unless it causes angular displacement. Only NET torque does.

Comment: @Qmechanic unfortunately it is not the same question. I'm trying to understand where is the hidden information that differentiate both measurements. I already said in the description I understand why they are different

Comment: The simple fact is that there are *way* more physical quantities than the are dimensional combinations. This type of coincidence is the rule, not an exception that calls for an explanation.