What is the equation of torque $\tau=r F\sin(\theta)$ or $\tau=kr F\sin(\theta)$?
A guy on Reddit claiming professor, says tau=k r Fsin(theta). I was like how but he said it is because tau is proportional to both r and Fsin(theta) and for this reason when we measure equality we find the k as a constant. Now can anyone clear this, if his statements are true are not?

It's true if $k$ is a dimensionless constant equal to $1$.

@JohnRennie yes he claims it dimensionless like F=kma. I chatted with him.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37881/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104101/2451 and links therein.

Thanks a lot @Qmechanic. So k really exists
