# Is (velocity=angular rotation*radius) dimensionally homogenous?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, angular-velocity

I have been driving myself mad trying to prove it one way or the other, I understand how it is derived and how to use it etc. but it still seems to me to be saying that **(m/s)=(rad/s)*(m)** which I don't think is dimensionally homogenous, what happens to the radians. Couldn't find anything on the internet about the homogenuity of it. I am probably just being stupid but please if anyone could shed some light on this that would be amazing.

Comment: Radians are dimensionless. Technically you have $m/s=(1/s)\cdot m$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about Radian as a unit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422617/)

Answer (score 0):

What you call angular rotation is angular velocity. The dimension of angular velocity is one over time, because the angle is dimensionless.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rotq.html I was just on this site and they said the angular velocity has the units radians/second, in the bit about angular velocity. Also I always thought that angular velocity=2*pi*f where f was rev/s. Am still a bit confused. Thanks for the speedy answer though.