# Derive SI units of Angular Acceleration from $\tau=I\cdot\alpha$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, dimensional-analysis, rotation, si-units

I am trying to drive that $[\alpha]=\mathrm{rad}/\mathrm{s^2}$ from $$\tau=I\cdot\alpha.$$
My try: $N\cdot m=\mathrm{kg}\cdot m^2 \cdot [\alpha]$, and as Newton is $\mathrm{kg}\cdot m/\mathrm{sec}^2$ then I got
$$[\alpha]=\frac{m\cdot \mathrm{kg}\cdot \frac{m}{\mathrm{sec}^2}}{\mathrm{kg}\cdot m^2}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{sec}^2}?$$

Thanks

Comment: That is correct (although you have a typo in the first mention of the Newton unit. The metre isn't squared in the numerator). The radian is a unit-less unit so what you got here is an equivalent result.

Comment: Angular acceleration is expressed in $rad/s^2$.  Radians are dimensionless, and are used to tell you how angles are measured.

Comment: @Steeven: May you explain why a radian is a unitless unit?

Comment: rad/s² is same as 1/s²

Comment: why does rad/$s^2$ be the same as $1/s^2$?

Comment: I get that radians are unitless but it does not tell me that I can put them whenever I want, does it?

Comment: A radian is a term for metre-per-metre. Equivalently, it is a "number of radiusses (radii)". Thus unitless

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/587176/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; the "rad" term does not appear in your answer because the number of radians an angle *is* is defined as the ratio of the arc of the sector it sweeps through to the radius of that sector. This ratio between two lengths ends up being a dimensionless number with no units, as it's a quantity in metres divided by a quantity in metres, despite the fact that its meaning may most effectively be communicated with the companion term "radians".

You can think of your answer as equivalent to (m/m)/s²; in informal terms, you might think of this as "the acceleration (m/s²) experienced by a point in an object on its circular path around the centre of mass, per unit length of the distance of that point away from the center of mass (1/m)", which has the same meaning as "the angular acceleration of the points in the object".